# How to list network interfaces, its configuration IP,netmask and gateway in Python/Windows

Tags: python, windows, networking

I wanna develop a small application to monitor arp and scan arp list in local network.

Currently, I need to retrieve the list of network interfaces and its configuration.

Most of the time I work with Linux, so I don't know much about Win32 API, is there anyway to do this in python way ? I'm using Python 2.6 with PyQt and Scapy (has pywin32 aswell, so if you provide the detail way with win32, I will try)

I found pcapy.findalldevs(), but it cannot retrive configuration. I don't care much about the name, just configuration(IP,netmask) is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what info you want, but `ipconfig /all` certainly sounds like what you want:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ipconfig /all')
```

Comment: that should be a good way, but I want a more python way so I ask here :)

Comment: @Fu4ny that's about as Python as it gets on Windows. Trust me, you don't want to use and Win32 APIs, they're a real pain

Comment: I did write a parse to get the configuration, a little hackish now but I think I should choose this.

Answer (score 3):

For a cross platform solution, I've used [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces).

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, I use [pynetlinux](https://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux/)

```
pip install pynetlinux==1.1
```

```
>>> from pynetlinux import ifconfig
>>> ifconfig.Interface("eth0").get_ip()
'192.168.1.66'
```

Edit:
This is indeed for Linux, for a cross-platform solution, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29851337/185510).